# PHP: Get class constants from static method using ReflectionClass

Tags: php, reflection, static

I'm attempting to get a list of class constants from within a static method.

```
public static function example()
{
  $reflection = new \ReflectionClass(get_called_class());
  var_dump($reflection -> getConstants());
}
```

Throws `Fatal error: Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active`

Is there any way for this to work, or am I up against another language limit in php?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried your code and it works fine could you provide an example of your actual class?

```
class test23 {
    const te = 'asd';
    var $ya = 'hoopla';
    public static function example()
    {
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass(get_called_class());
        var_dump($reflection -> getConstants());
    }
}
```

`test23::example();` returns `array(1) { ["te"]=> string(3) "asd" }`

Answer (score -2):

```
// creates a reflection class object
$reflection = new ReflectionClass ( $this );

//gets all the constants of the current class 
$consts = $reflection->getConstants ();
```

hope it helps.